# HiddenInput(DisplayValue=false) trips up add-migration?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I can fix this myself each time I need to update my model.. but it is annoying and surely I have done something to inflict this pain upon myself.

Each time I update the model (add-migration) for the context which contains these entities, I have to go through and first comment out everywhere I have annotated [HiddenInput(DisplayValue=false)] on a primary key.  Then I an add the migration.. update the database.. then finally I have to go back and uncomment all the HiddenInput's once again to actually get the GUI behavior I want.

This HiddenInput does not actually impact the running version of the code... if it is there or not, EntityFramework still believes it is hookingup to the same database schema it seems and works fine either way.  And this is as it should be in my opinion.

I don't understand why I have to remove the HiddenInput's in order to do my add-migration/update-database steps.  I don't get it.

An example...

```
public class ET_APIKeyErrors
{
    [Key]
    /*mvc*/[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public long apiKeyErrorId { get; set; }

    public String errorAction { get; set; }
    public String errorResponse { get; set; }
    public String errorCode { get; set; }

    #region subitems
    public virtual ET_APIKey apiKey { get; set; }
    #endregion subitems
}
```

Before using add-migration, I have to go change /*mvc*/ to //mvc
Then I an add-migration, and update-database
After which I replace all //mvc with /*mvc* once again.

If I forget this step, I am quickly reminded by the errors I get from model generation like so...

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

App.ET_APIKey: : EntityType 'ET_APIKey' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
APIKeys: EntityType: EntitySet 'APIKeys' is based on type 'ET_APIKey' that has no keys defined.
```

Comment: Make separate ViewModels.  Your EF CodeFirst entities should not getting edited directly in your views.